# How can I focus on a subset of a list in python

Tags: python, list

I run across this problem frequently suppose I have a text file that I have read in as as a list using file.readlines()

suppose the file looks something like this

```
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff #indeterminate number of line \
The text I want is set off by something distinctive
I want this
I want this
I want this
I want this # indeterminate number of lines
The end is also identifiable by something distinctive
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
```

The way I have been handling this is to do something like this

```
themasterlist=[]
for file in filelist:
    count=0
    templist=[]
    for line in file:
        if line=='The text I want is set off by something distinctive':
            count=1
        if line=='The end is also identifiable by something distinctive':
            count=0
        if count==1:
        templist.append(line)
   themasterlist.append(templist)
```

I have thought about using the string (file.read()) and splitting it based on the end points and then converting it to a list but actually I want to use this construction for a number of other types.  For example, suppose I am iterating through the elements of an lxml.fromstring(somefile) and I want to process a subset of the elements based on whether or not the element.text contains some phrase etc.

Note, I could be running through 200K to 300K files at a time.

My solution works but it feels clunky and like I am missing something important about python

There are three really good answers and I learned something useful from each.  I need to select one as the answer but I do appreciate the response of each poster it was very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like stuff like this:

```
def findblock( lines, start, stop ):
    it = iter(lines)
    for line in it:
        if start in line:
            # now we are in the block, so yield till we find the end
            for line in it:
                if stop in line:
                    # lets just look for one block
                    return # leave this generator
                    # break # would keep looking for the next block
                yield line                

for line in findblock(lines, start="something distinctive", 
                             stop="something distinctive"):
    print line
```

The stuff you were missing is yield and list comprehensions - here is your code revised:

```
def findblock( lines, start='The text I want is set off by something distinctive', 
                      stop='The end is also identifiable by something distinctive'):
    for line in lines:
        inblock = False
        if line==start:
            inblock=True
        if line==stop:
            inblock=False # or return mb?
        if inblock:
            yield line

themasterlist = [list(findblock( file )) for file in files]
```

Comment: Generators are certainly the more Pythonic way of doing this. Using a list instead may use an excessive amount of memory.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
data = list(filelist)
topindex = data.index('The text I want is set off by something distinctive')
endindex = data.index('The end is also identifiable by something distinctive')
themasterlist = data[topindex+1:endindex]
```

The above will throw exceptions if your distinctive text is not found, so be prepared for that. Note also that I made sure `data` is a list, since despite the name I couldn't be sure that `filelist` was a list or not (it could be an iterator).

Comment: Amazing thanks that is really cool  I suppose it works that thematerlist.append(data[topindex+1:endindex]) so I am there

Comment: Using `.append()` probably won't do quite what you want. That will append the *single* list slice from `data` onto the end of `themasterlist`. If you want to copy the slice onto the end of `themasterlist`, use `.extend()` instead of `.append()`.

Comment: Note that this will (a) read all the files' data into RAM, and then (b) seek through it twice to find the two lines.  Substituting `data[topindex:].index(...) + topindex` for the `endindex` assignment will resolve (b), I believe.

Comment: note also that `.index(...)` returns only the index of the first occurence, so if you have multiple items in one file this will have to be placed in a loop where you successively chop off bits of the list.

Answer (score 1):

If there is exactly one block of interest per file, you could do

```
from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile
startline = "The text I want is set off by something distinctive"
endline = "The end is also identifiable by something distinctive"
masterlist = []
for file in filelist:
    next(dropwhile(lambda line: line != startline, file))
    masterlist.append(list(takewhile(lambda line: line != endline, file)))
```

If there is an unknown number of blocks per file, this gets a bit less elegant though:

```
for file in filelist:
    templist = []
    while True:
        try:
            next(dropwhile(lambda line: line != startline, file))
            masterlist += takewhile(lambda line: line != endline, file)
        except StopIteration:
            break
   masterlist.append(templist)
```

Note that this code assumes that `filelist` is a list of open file objects.